# How to give a Borel set whose projection is not Borel?

Tags: real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

I wonder that how Suslin got the idea "analytic set" and the advanced knowledge in this field.

Can anyone explain this simply or recommend some reference?

All discussions and comments are welcome.

Comment: As currently phrased, the answer is trivial[1]. Maybe you mean something else? [1]: Just take $\{(p,0^\omega) \mid p \text{ codes an ill-founded tree}\}$.

Comment: The example you ask is trivial: take to horizontal planes, and consider the set which consists of arbitrary set (non-Borel) in one of them and entire second plane. The vertical projection of this set is a plane. The example which led to discovery of analytic set is different: it is  a Borel set whose projection is not Borel.

Comment: I think you're looking for a Borel set whose projection is not Borel.

Comment: And the way a Borel set whose projection is not Borel is usually constructed is by constructing a $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1$-universal set, which then cannot be Borel, because self-dual pointclasses are easily shown not to have universal sets

Comment: As for how the notion of analytic sets was discovered that happened because Lebesgue wrote a paper in which he "proved" that the projection of a Borel set is Borel and Suslin noticed this mistake

Comment: @A.Bailleul Yes. Sorry, it is my fault. I'll modify my question.

Comment: @Arno Yes. Thank you for your answer. I mean a Borel set whose projection is not Borel

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Right. My fault

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti With all my gratitude, can you explain it more, or offer my some references?

Comment: @YOTAL look at theorem 14.2 in Kechris *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, in this theorem an analytic but not Borel subset of $\mathcal N^2$ is constructed, which answers your question as well since any analytic subset of $\mathcal N^2$ is the projection of a Borel subset of $\mathcal N^3$ by definition

Answer (score 1):

I like the presentation of descriptive set theory found in Chapter 8 of

*Cohn, Donald L.*, Measure theory., Boston, MA: Birkhäuser. ix, 373 p. (1993). [ZBL0860.28001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0860.28001).